# Oracle Riddle, using 'IN' versus using 'Or'

Tags: sql, oracle

The question is simple, I have two pieces of code and do not understand how they produce different results. In fact, the first piece of code in some instances produces over twice as many results as the second piece of code. Please help me to understand how these differ, I thought they would perform the same thing.

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*), EYSOURCESYSTEM
FROM MERCK_SCSA_1028_THIRD_RN
WHERE TRIM(PAYMENTTERMS) = '0' OR TRIM(PAYMENTTERMS) = '0.000'
AND POSTINGDATEYEAR = '2014'
GROUP BY EYSOURCESYSTEM
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

versus

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*), EYSOURCESYSTEM
FROM MERCK_SCSA_1028_THIRD_RN
WHERE TRIM(PAYMENTTERMS) IN ('0', '0.000')
AND POSTINGDATEYEAR = '2014'
GROUP BY EYSOURCESYSTEM
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: Without parentheses around your `OR` condition, order of operations is going to bite you in that first example. Since `AND` gets applied first, the `TRIM(PAYMENTTERMS) = '0.000'` will get grouped with the `AND POSTINGDATEYEAR = '2014'` instead of the `OR` Here's a quick example of what I mean: http://www.praetoriate.com/t_garmany_easysql_sql_logical_operators.htm

Comment: It always helps to generate an explain plan in situations like this, so you can easily spot where the execution plans of the two queries diverge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first is like

> paymentterms == '0' || paymentterms == '0.000' && postingdateyear = '2014'

(EDIT 1: Please see the [Operator Precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/operator-precedence.html) reference; note that `&&` is of a higher priority than `||`)

Your first statement will be evaluated as the following:

> paymentterms == '0' || (paymentterms == '0.000' && postingdateyear = '2014')

In contrast, your second is like

> (paymentterms == '0' || paymentterms == '0.000') && postingdateyear = '2014'

Because they are being evaluated in a different order, the first and second statements are not performing the same query.

Edit 2: Adding a Venn diagram.

You are getting more rows returned because of the extraneous `'0' but not '2014'` green section in the first diagram. 
[image: Venn Diagram of query 1 vs query 2]

Your second query, with the `IN`, seems to be the correct one.

Comment: For the OP to understand why your answer is correct and how to solve his issue a [short explanation of logical operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/operator-precedence.html) like in @valverij's comment would really improve this answer, because if he knew about it he wouldn't have asked.

Comment: Good point, @timo.rieber. I have added the link and improved the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Comment and other answer are correct, but just thought I'd try to clarify for you:

```
WHERE TRIM(PAYMENTTERMS) IN ('0', '0.000') 
  AND POSTINGDATEYEAR = '2014'
```

Includes only records with `POSTINGDATEYEAR` of 2014 that also have `PAYMENTTERMS` of either 0/0.0000,

While:

```
WHERE TRIM(PAYMENTTERMS) = '0' 
   OR TRIM(PAYMENTTERMS) = '0.000'
  AND POSTINGDATEYEAR = '2014'
```

Includes all records with `PAYMENTTERMS` of 0 regardless of year, and also records with `PAYMENTTERMS` of 0.000 with `POSTINGDATEYEAR` of 2014.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the parentheses the way the database does it gets obvious:

The first one is equivalent to:

```
WHERE (TRIM(PAYMENTTERMS) = '0') 
   OR (TRIM(PAYMENTTERMS) = '0.000' AND POSTINGDATEYEAR = '2014')
```

while the second one is equivalent to:

```
WHERE (TRIM(PAYMENTTERMS) = '0' OR TRIM(PAYMENTTERMS) = '0.000')
  AND (POSTINGDATEYEAR = '2014')
```