# How mixed AND's and OR's are nested in a SQL when not specified parenthesis?

Tags: sql

In this SQL:

```
select * from cars
where brand='VW' or year=1974 and active=true or active is null
```

How does common database engines nest the operators being that parenthesis were not typed?

I mean, something like `(brand='VW' or year=1974) and (active=true or active is null)`

Or maybe `brand='VW' or (year=1974 and active=true) or active is null`?

Comment: Please see the Operator Precedence link at http://stackoverflow.com/a/26895161/509840

Answer (score 1):

AND is higher than OR. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/operator-precedence.html.

That site lists the operator precedence:

```
INTERVAL
BINARY, COLLATE
!
- (unary minus), ~ (unary bit inversion)
^
*, /, DIV, %, MOD
-, +
<<, >>
&
|
= (comparison), <=>, >=, >, <=, <, <>, !=, IS, LIKE, REGEXP, IN
BETWEEN, CASE, WHEN, THEN, ELSE
NOT
AND, &&
XOR
OR, ||
= (assignment), :=
```

In your example,

```
where brand='VW' or year=1974 and active=true or active is null
```

would be addressed with the IS first, the AND next, and the OR last, as in:

```
where (brand='VW' or (year=1974 and active=true)) or (active is null)
```

Comment: Note that this can (and does) vary between RDBMS implementations, so don't assume Oracle is the gospel.  See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx

Comment: @Donnie, nice. Your link shows that MS SQL would not necessarily execute the OP's string in the order that I gave. Rather, it would process the AND first, then the OR next. Unfortunately, the chart does not show whether the IS NULL comes before or after those two operations. If the IS NULL came first (and I suspect that it does), then it would be identical to the Oracle order.

Comment: I was more referring to the overall precedence.  For example, compare bitwise not in mssql to Oracle.  It's important when asking implementation dependent question to specify an implementation.

Comment: The OP was asking about AND and OR operators. When just observing these two, AND takes precedence over the OR in these SQL implementations: Oracle and MySQL, MS SQL, Postgres (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/6.5/static/operators.htm).  It also follows the same precedence in Java (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), C++ (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). I think that would satisfy the OP's question.